# Какое подлежащее в предложении «нам нравятся песни Высоцкого»?

Tags: синтаксис

> Нам нравятся песни Высоцкого.

Какое  подлежащее в предложении?

Answer (score 1):

Нравятся песни - грамматическая основа, песни - подлежащее.

НРАВИТЬСЯ,  (кому). 1. Производить на кого-л. хорошее, приятное впечатление, вызывать расположение к себе. Вам нравится новый сотрудник? Мне нравилось выражение её лица. Город начал ей н.